# pygame.sprite.groupcollide() does not work when trying to implement collision in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, collision

I'm working on a Snake Game project, and I can't make the snake and the foods collide. After reading some Pygame documentation, I decided to use `pygame.sprite.groupcollide` for collisions. I have two types of sprites in my game:

1. Snake
2. Food(s)

`pygame.sprite.groupcollide` has worked in my previous game (Alien Invasion game from a Python book); however, for some reason it doesn't work in my current game. What do you think might be the reason? Here is the higlight of the collisions part (snake_game.py):

```
def _check_snake_food_collisions(self):
        '''Check the collisions between the snake and foods.'''
        collisions = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(self.foods, self.snake_parts, True, False)
```

Here is my code:

**snake_game.py**

```
import pygame
import sys

from random import randint

from settings import Settings 
from snake import Snake
from food import Food 

class SnakeGame:
    '''The main class of the game.'''

    def __init__(self):
        '''Initialize the game assets, screen, etc.'''
        pygame.init()
        self.settings = Settings()
        
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.settings.screen_width,
                            self.settings.screen_height))
        pygame.display.set_caption("Snake Game")

        self.snake_parts = pygame.sprite.Group() #Will do some refactoring here.
        self.snake_part = Snake(self)  # Will move this part elsewhere.
        self.snake_parts.add(self.snake_part)
        
        self.foods = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.food = Food(self)          # Will do some refactoring here as well.
        self.foods.add(self.food)       # Will move this part elsewhere.
       
    def run_game(self):
        '''The main loop of the game.'''
        while True:
            self._check_events()
            self._update_snake_parts()
            self._update_screen()

    def _check_events(self):
        '''Check all the events.'''
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                self._check_keydown_events(event)
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                self._check_keyup_events(event)

    def _check_keydown_events(self, event):
        '''Check keydown events.'''
        if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_w:
            self.snake_part.m_up = True
        elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN or event.key == pygame.K_s:
            self.snake_part.m_down = True
        elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_a:
            self.snake_part.m_left = True
        elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == pygame.K_d:
            self.snake_part.m_right = True
        elif event.key == pygame.K_q:
            sys.exit()

    def _check_keyup_events(self, event):
        '''Check keyup events.'''
        if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_w:
            self.snake_part.m_up = False
        elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN or event.key == pygame.K_s:
            self.snake_part.m_down = False
        elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_a:
            self.snake_part.m_left = False
        elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == pygame.K_d:
            self.snake_part.m_right = False

    def _check_snake_food_collisions(self):
        '''Check the collisions between the snake and foods.'''
        collisions = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(self.foods, self.snake_parts, True, False)
      
    def _update_snake_parts(self):
        '''Update all the parts of the snake.'''
        self.snake_parts.update()
        
    def _update_screen(self):
        '''Update the screen.'''
        self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)

        # Draw snake parts to the screen.
        for snake_part in self.snake_parts.sprites():
            snake_part.draw_part()

        # Draw foods to the screen.
        self.food.draw_food()

        pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sg = SnakeGame()
    sg.run_game()
```

---

**snake.py**

```
import pygame
import sys

from pygame.sprite import Sprite 

class Snake(Sprite):
    '''A class to manage the snake.'''

    def __init__(self, sg):
        '''Initialize the snake's location, size, etc.'''
        super().__init__()
        self.screen = sg.screen
        self.settings = sg.settings
        self.color = self.settings.snake_color
        self.screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()
        
        # Create the snake's rect object and position it.
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(0,0, self.settings.snake_width,
                            self.settings.snake_height)
        self.rect.center = self.screen_rect.center

        # Get the precise coordinates of the snake.
        self.x = float(self.rect.x)
        self.y = float(self.rect.y)

        # Set movement flags.
        self.m_right = False
        self.m_left = False
        self.m_up = False
        self.m_down = False

    def update(self):
        '''Update the position of the snake.'''
        if self.m_right and self.rect.right < self.screen_rect.right:                    
            self.x += self.settings.snake_speed
        if self.m_left and self.rect.left > self.screen_rect.left:
            self.x -= self.settings.snake_speed
        if self.m_down and self.rect.bottom < self.screen_rect.bottom:
            self.y += self.settings.snake_speed
        if self.m_up and self.rect.top > self.screen_rect.top:
            self.y -= self.settings.snake_speed

        self.rect.x = self.x
        self.rect.y = self.y
        
    def draw_part(self):
        '''Draw the snake to the screen.'''
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.color, self.rect)
```

---

**food.py**

```
import pygame

from random import randint
from pygame.sprite import Sprite 

class Food(Sprite):
    '''A class to manage the foods.'''

    def __init__(self, sg):
        '''Initialize the food rect, food color, and other assets.'''
        super().__init__()
        self.screen = sg.screen
        self.settings = sg.settings
        self.color = self.settings.food_color
        
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, self.settings.food_width,
                        self.settings.food_height)

        # Initialize the food at a random position.
        self.spawn_food()
    
    def spawn_food(self):
        '''Position the food at a random position.'''
        self.rect.x = randint(0, self.settings.screen_width - 
                        self.settings.food_width) 
        self.rect.y = randint(0, self.settings.screen_height - 
                        self.settings.food_height) 

    def draw_food(self):
        '''Draw the food to the screen.'''
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.color, self.rect)
```

---

**settings.py**

```
class Settings:
    '''Class for game settings.'''

    def __init__(self):
        '''Initialize the game settings.'''

        # Screen settings
        self.screen_width = 1200
        self.screen_height = 800
        self.bg_color = (119, 181, 254)  # Blue color

        # Snake settings
        self.snake_width = 20
        self.snake_height = 20
        self.snake_color = (255, 255, 0)  # Yellow color
        self.snake_speed = 1

        # Food settings
        self.food_width = 10
        self.food_height = 10
        self.food_color = (139, 69, 19)  # Brown color
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the documentation of [`pygame.sprite.groupcollide`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.groupcollide):

> [...] If either dokill argument is True, the colliding Sprites will be removed from their respective Group.

When you do

> ```py
> collisions = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(self.foods, self.snake_parts, True, False)
> ```

and a collision is detected and the food is removed from the [*Group*](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group) `self.foods`.
However, the `self.food` attribute still refers to the `Food` object.

The food is in the *Group* until a collision is detected. Hence you have to draw the objects in the *Group* `self.foods` rather than the [*Sprite*](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) object `self.food`. You don't even need the `self.food` attribute. It is sufficient if all `Food` objects are contained in `self.foods`:

<s>`self.food.draw_food()`</s>

```py
for food in self.foods.sprites():
    food.draw_food()
```

---

Please note, that `_check_snake_food_collisions` is actually not called in your code.